# how to extract a number from text file (or do a query on a site to get that number to bat file

Tags: string, batch-file, integer

I'm trying to write a bat file that would use output of https://www.feathercoin.com/netstats/

I need current network difficulty

I used curl to extract the contents of the webpage and findstr to write output of a string that contains difficulty to a file:
here's how file looks=

```
Current Block Number: В  1971095
Current Hashrate in Kh/s: В  2714249.165
Next retarget block number: В  1971096
Blocks to next retarget: В  1
Current difficulty: В  24.29714508
Expected next difficulty: В  26.496224436026
Time to retarget in second: В  34.366666666667
Total number of Feathercoins: В  182244280
```

in hex:

```
3C 68 31 3E 3C 2F 68 31 3E 3C 70 3E 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 42 6C 6F 63 6B 20 4E 75 6D 62 65 72 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 39 37 31 30 39 35 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 48 61 73 68 72 61 74 65 20 69 6E 20 4B 68 2F 73 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 37 31 34 32 34 39 2E 31 36 35 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 4E 65 78 74 20 72 65 74 61 72 67 65 74 20 62 6C 6F 63 6B 20 6E 75 6D 62 65 72 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 39 37 31 30 39 36 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 42 6C 6F 63 6B 73 20 74 6F 20 6E 65 78 74 20 72 65 74 61 72 67 65 74 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 64 69 66 66 69 63 75 6C 74 79 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 34 2E 32 39 37 31 34 35 30 38 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 45 78 70 65 63 74 65 64 20 6E 65 78 74 20 64 69 66 66 69 63 75 6C 74 79 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 36 2E 34 39 36 32 32 34 34 33 36 30 32 36 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 54 69 6D 65 20 74 6F 20 72 65 74 61 72 67 65 74 20 69 6E 20 73 65 63 6F 6E 64 3A 20 C2 A0 20 33 34 2E 33 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 37 3C 62 72 20 2F 3E 54 6F 74 61 6C 20 6E 75 6D 62 65 72 20 6F 66 20 46 65 61 74 68 65 72 63 6F 69 6E 73 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 38 32 32 34 34 32 38 30 0A
```

further i tried

```
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1-10" %%I in ("b.txt") do (
 SET I=%%I && SET J=%%J && SET K=%%K && SET L=%%L && SET M=%%M && CALL :ECHO %%I
)
```

That does not get me anywhere any suggestions on how to get `current difficulty` to a `%%I` would be appreciated!

If i can get `feathercoin difficulty` to a variable i'd be able to control which `miner` to use depending on the `network difficulty` of the feather coin thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following code for file `b.txt` being UTF-8 encoded and containing a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) **on each line**:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-3*" %%A in ('type "b.txt"') do (
    if /I "%%A %%B" == "Current difficulty:" (
        set "CurrentDifficulty=%%D"
        goto HaveDifficulty
    )
)
echo Upps, could not find current difficulty.
goto :EOF

:HaveDifficulty
echo Current difficulty is: %CurrentDifficulty%
```

The file `b.txt` is not processed directly by **FOR** line by line because **FOR** fails to correct process Unicode text files. Instead the command **TYPE** is used to output the content of this file in ANSI (or more precise in OEM) in a separate command process started by **FOR** in background with `cmd /C` and captured by **FOR**.

Each line of captured output not being empty or starting with a semicolon is split up by **FOR** into four substrings (tokens) using the default delimiters normal space and horizontal tab.

The first tab/space separated string is assigned to loop variable `A` which is on the line of interest the string `Current`. The second tab/space separated string `difficulty:` is assigned to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is `B`. The third string is the strange character being of no interest and assigned to loop variable `C`. And the fourth string is the rest of the line after tabs/spaces after third string which is on line of interest the string `24.29714508`.

A case-insensitive **IF** condition is used to check if the first two substrings of current line concatenated with a space is `Current difficulty:`. If that condition is true, the right line is found in output of the file. For that reason the fourth string is assigned to environment variable `CurrentDifficulty` and the loop is exited without processing the other lines of captured output with a jump in batch file processing to a defined label.

It is expected by this batch file that the UTF-8 encoded file contains the bytes:

```
0000h: 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 42 6C 6F 63 6B 20 4E 75 ; Current Block Nu
0010h: 6D 62 65 72 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 39 37 31 30 39 35 ; mber: Â  1971095
0020h: 0D 0A 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 48 61 73 68 72 61 ; ..Current Hashra
0030h: 74 65 20 69 6E 20 4B 68 2F 73 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 ; te in Kh/s: Â  2
0040h: 37 31 34 32 34 39 2E 31 36 35 0D 0A 4E 65 78 74 ; 714249.165..Next
0050h: 20 72 65 74 61 72 67 65 74 20 62 6C 6F 63 6B 20 ;  retarget block 
0060h: 6E 75 6D 62 65 72 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 39 37 31 30 ; number: Â  19710
0070h: 39 36 0D 0A 42 6C 6F 63 6B 73 20 74 6F 20 6E 65 ; 96..Blocks to ne
0080h: 78 74 20 72 65 74 61 72 67 65 74 3A 20 C2 A0 20 ; xt retarget: Â  
0090h: 31 0D 0A 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 64 69 66 66 69 ; 1..Current diffi
00a0h: 63 75 6C 74 79 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 34 2E 32 39 37 ; culty: Â  24.297
00b0h: 31 34 35 30 38 0D 0A 45 78 70 65 63 74 65 64 20 ; 14508..Expected 
00c0h: 6E 65 78 74 20 64 69 66 66 69 63 75 6C 74 79 3A ; next difficulty:
00d0h: 20 C2 A0 20 32 36 2E 34 39 36 32 32 34 34 33 36 ;  Â  26.496224436
00e0h: 30 32 36 0D 0A 54 69 6D 65 20 74 6F 20 72 65 74 ; 026..Time to ret
00f0h: 61 72 67 65 74 20 69 6E 20 73 65 63 6F 6E 64 3A ; arget in second:
0100h: 20 C2 A0 20 33 34 2E 33 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 ;  Â  34.366666666
0110h: 36 36 37 0D 0A 54 6F 74 61 6C 20 6E 75 6D 62 65 ; 667..Total numbe
0120h: 72 20 6F 66 20 46 65 61 74 68 65 72 63 6F 69 6E ; r of Feathercoin
0130h: 73 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 38 32 32 34 34 32 38 30 0D ; s: Â  182244280.
0140h: 0A                                              ; .
```

But if the file does not even contain carriage return `0D` and line-feed `0A`, but is a single "line" with all the words and floating point numbers, the batch file above fails to extract the floating point number of current difficulty from this text file.

But the UTF-8 encoded `b.txt` contains in real the text:

```
Current Block Number:   1971095Current Hashrate in Kh/s:   2714249.165Next retarget block number:   1971096Blocks to next retarget:   1Current difficulty:   24.29714508Expected next difficulty:   26.496224436026Time to retarget in second:   34.366666666667Total number of Feathercoins:   182244280
```

The hexadecimal representation with file offset (left side) and Windows-1252 representation (right side) is:

```
0000h: 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 42 6C 6F 63 6B 20 4E 75 ; Current Block Nu
0010h: 6D 62 65 72 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 39 37 31 30 39 35 ; mber: Â  1971095
0020h: 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 20 48 61 73 68 72 61 74 65 ; Current Hashrate
0030h: 20 69 6E 20 4B 68 2F 73 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 37 31 ;  in Kh/s: Â  271
0040h: 34 32 34 39 2E 31 36 35 4E 65 78 74 20 72 65 74 ; 4249.165Next ret
0050h: 61 72 67 65 74 20 62 6C 6F 63 6B 20 6E 75 6D 62 ; arget block numb
0060h: 65 72 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 39 37 31 30 39 36 42 6C ; er: Â  1971096Bl
0070h: 6F 63 6B 73 20 74 6F 20 6E 65 78 74 20 72 65 74 ; ocks to next ret
0080h: 61 72 67 65 74 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 43 75 72 72 65 ; arget: Â  1Curre
0090h: 6E 74 20 64 69 66 66 69 63 75 6C 74 79 3A 20 C2 ; nt difficulty: Â
00a0h: A0 20 32 34 2E 32 39 37 31 34 35 30 38 45 78 70 ;   24.29714508Exp
00b0h: 65 63 74 65 64 20 6E 65 78 74 20 64 69 66 66 69 ; ected next diffi
00c0h: 63 75 6C 74 79 3A 20 C2 A0 20 32 36 2E 34 39 36 ; culty: Â  26.496
00d0h: 32 32 34 34 33 36 30 32 36 54 69 6D 65 20 74 6F ; 224436026Time to
00e0h: 20 72 65 74 61 72 67 65 74 20 69 6E 20 73 65 63 ;  retarget in sec
00f0h: 6F 6E 64 3A 20 C2 A0 20 33 34 2E 33 36 36 36 36 ; ond: Â  34.36666
0100h: 36 36 36 36 36 36 37 54 6F 74 61 6C 20 6E 75 6D ; 6666667Total num
0110h: 62 65 72 20 6F 66 20 46 65 61 74 68 65 72 63 6F ; ber of Featherco
0120h: 69 6E 73 3A 20 C2 A0 20 31 38 32 32 34 34 32 38 ; ins: Â  18224428
0130h: 30                                              ; 0
```

For such a file a different approach is needed to get the floating point number of `Current difficulty`. I suggest to use [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** being stored in current directory on execution of the batch file posted below.

```
@echo off
set "CurrentDifficulty="
for /F %%I in ('jrepl.bat "^.*Current difficulty:[^0-9.]+([0-9.]+).*$" "$1" /M /F b.txt') do set "CurrentDifficulty=%%I"

if not defined CurrentDifficulty (
    echo Upps, could not find current difficulty.
    goto :EOF
)

echo Current difficulty is: %CurrentDifficulty%
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `type /?`